# Asp.net search database from textbox except when specific strings are entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, lotus

I have created an asp.net application where a user can enter a name in a textbox to search a lotus notes database. Whenever a name is entered, say "Robert", the code behind will search the database and display all the results (all entries called "Robert") in a gridview.

Problem is that my database has like 170 000+ entries. So loading them all at the same time is impossible. It takes ages to load the page and then the browser just time out.

So I fixed this problem in a simple way. I coded my app so that it stops loading entries whenever it has already loaded 2000. This way, the display of the page is a lot quicker.

But, if I type "Robert" in the textbox and then click the ok button, no entries are displayed. Because the application does not iterate through more than 2000 entries in the database.

So I thought about a fix. Whenever a user enters "[2000]" in the textbox, the page will load again, but this time it will start to load entries after the index specified between the "[ ]" (i.e. 2000). This way, we would be able to access entries that are far beyond the 2000 cap without affecting the time to display the page.

But there is a problem. Whenever I enter "[2000]" in the textbox, the app searches for entries called "[2000]" in the database. Is there a way to add exceptions to the research? Like when I enter a specific string it processes a different code instead of looking that text up in the database?

I don't have any code to give you now as I am writing this at home and the code is at my office. If you really need some code, I will see what I can do tomorrow. But if someone could provide me with an example of code that does what I am looking for, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>` and web services to load the data on the page init itself.

Below is an example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" MaxLength="80" class="form-control"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt1" ServiceMethod="returntxt1Data"
MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="0" EnableCaching="false" OnClientItemSelected="ItemSelected">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

write a javascript to postback :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ItemSelected(sender, args) {
        __doPostBack(sender.get_element().name, "");
    }
</script>
```

In .cs page, create a static variable an load that variable in `Page_Init`

```
public static List<string> List1= new List<string>(); 

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List1= LoadData(); //one time load data from database.
}
```

Then create a webservice to display autocomplete accordingly.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static List<string> returntxt1Data(string prefixText)
        {
            List<string> newlist1 = new List<string>();

            foreach (string a in List1)
            {
                if (a.ToUpper().Contains(prefixText.ToUpper()))
                {
                    newlist1.Add(a);
                }
            }
            return newlist1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is pretty troubling your code as well. To search a database using a keyword these are what you should do. 
I have not used Lotus Note before so the general algorithm is

1. Use "WHERE Name LIKE %keyword%" statement for short keywords search
2. Use FULLTEXT-SEARCH when your keyword is a sentence, like title of an article or so.
3. Always use the "TOP {pagesize}" in sqlserver or "LIMIT {pagesize}" in mysql. This will limit the number of records to return and then add pagination to keep searching if there are more data matches. (there should be an equivalent of this in Lotus Note)
4. Make sure the textbox is not empty to avoid unnecessary calls to database

Try them out...